# IBM Data Studio (Admin client) version 3.1.1

Tags: ibm-midrange, ibm-data-studio

Simple question that I can't find an answer to.

I am validating Data Studio (admin version) for use at our site. Most of it looks OK apart from trying to use the wizard to build row value SQL expressions such as

```
Update cmf a set (cftlvl,cfplvl) =
 (select cftlvl,cfplvl from fixes b where a.cffac=b.cffac and a.cfcset=b.cfcset and a.cfcbkt=b.cfcbkt and a.cfprod=b.cfprod)
where (a.cffac,a.cfcset,a.cfcbkt,a.cfprod) in (select cffac,cfcset,cfcbkt,cfprod from fixes)
```

The code runs fine but the wizard will not build the 'IN' clause properly. It will not accept a list of values in the predicate.

I can't find any documentation, anyone know if this is possible.

Comment: I'm aware of only a single mention, at the end of [Multiple search conditions within a WHERE clause](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/sqlp/rbafymultiplewhere.htm?lang=en): "Lists can only be used with the equal and not equal comparison operators." Not clearly exact, but possibly a match.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll use EXISTS instead, backward step but seems to work.